# How do I add a background to my python project?

Tags: python, image, text, background, adventure

I’m a beginner programmer, and I’m working on a text adventure. I want to add a background picture to add to the aesthetic. I’ve tried multiple codes to download the background I want, but none of them have worked. Does anyone have a solution that 100 percent works?

Comment: What are you using for graphics in your game? Is it 100% text in a plain console? If that's the case, it unlikely that you'd be able to add a background unless you found a specific console that supported backgrounds.